# Winter Bash 2015: Hats are coming again!

Tags: discussion, hats

### It's almost time for Winter Bash 2015!

The last few years, Stack Exchange has run a holiday event called [Winter Bash](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash-2012)! It's a fun little event where users collect "hats" that you can wear on your avatars by doing various things (post on a certain day, get a question to a certain score, and things like that).

Each year, they ask us if we'd like to participate. The last few years we had a lot of fun with it, so I'm assuming we'll want to participate again this year! :-) The event will start on December 14, 2015, and it'll run until January 3, 2016. After that, the hats we've earned will all disappear.

Of course, if everyone suddenly decided they hated hats, we could opt out, but that doesn't seem very likely.  So, unless the community objects . . .

### Hats are coming again soon! :-)

*(**Note**: Users who don't want to see hats will be able to click a button labeled "I hate hats".)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope everyone enjoyed Winter Bash this year! :-)

As promised, [hats have disappeared](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26591458#26591458).  For the moment, you can still see the hats you got on [the Winter Bash 2015 website](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), although I'm not sure how long those'll stick around, so you might want to take a screen shot if you want to save your collection.

If you have any suggestions for things to do differently next year, there's a thread on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272294/215040) where you can post them.  (You can post here, too, but a lot more people will see it over there.  Our per-site meta has basically zero hat discussion.)